# How to list these jobs on a job application?

Tags: applications

Last year I worked for a school district under a contract. I worked for two schools, but it was one job. This year I am working for the same school district, but this time I’m a substitute teacher. I’m not under any contract. Would I be able to list these jobs as two separate employers on a job application even though it’s the same school district? Thanks for your help.

Comment response: I’m not questioning how to list the two jobs on a job application, since that was one job. I’m asking about working for the same school district back to back years under a different role.

Comment response: no I was not a substitute teacher last year, I was “elementary music prep teacher.”

Answer (score 2):

You should list the school district as the employer, because you only had one employer, just two locations.

You can separate them under 'Duties performed' or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

If the roles are related, list 1 section with the most recent (best) role.  If they're unrelated... you would want two sections.

When filling out the job app, you would list both roles and the start / end dates for them as two entries regardless.